# Using if statements in the body of email Excel to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am lost on how to tackle this part of the project I have undertaken for my company. I have created thus far, code that will filter, search for count of times an item is mentioned, and store it into a variable.

I have 20 of these items and I need to send an email out with the amount of times an item was mentioned.

I would rather just send an email that shows only the items that were mentioned and leave the rest out.

Doing this in Excel is the hard part as I am unsure how to code it in the body. Any help on sending me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EX.

```
Item 1,
Item 1,
Item 2,
Item 3.

VarForItem1 = 2 

VarForItem2 = 1 

VarForItem3 = 1

VarForItem4 = 0

VarForItem5 = 0
```

etc.

I want the email to only show the Vars that have greater than 0.

Comment: I had an idea, maybe I could use a 2 dimensional array and append only elements that are greater than zero to the array along with their corresponding item name. Item 1 has 5. Does anyone have a better solution than this though?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, with a combination of if statements underneath the calculation and a strmessage string. I just added the line with the amount if it was above 0.

```
If item1 > 0 then
   strmessage = strmessage & "Item 1 - " & strmessage & vbnewline
End if
```